# No module named 'pytest' with Python3.9 and Miniconda

Tags: python, pytest, conda, ubuntu-18.04

I have **Ubuntu 18.04** and I have installed **Miniconda** and **python 3.9**

I have pytest installed and verify it like so:

```
which pytest
/usr/bin/pytest
```

When I try to import it from python I get the error: **'No module named 'pytest'**

```
python3
Python 3.9.5 (default, Jun  4 2021, 12:28:51) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pytest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `pytest` installed, but not in your conda env - `/usr/bin/pytest` is not a location that `conda` installs to. You need to install it by running

```
conda install -c conda-forge pytest
```